# Why the changes doesn't get reflected in while loop javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am doing the `learnyounode` tutorials. I am at the ninth tutorial, in which I am wanted to send three HTTP requests in an order to get results and get those responses in the same order. I have written the below code, but variables I check constantly seem `null` in the while loop, so it stucks at infinite loop. Can anyone tell me why?

```
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async')

let holder = [
    {
        url: process.argv[2],
        data: null
    },
    {
        url: process.argv[3],
        data: null
    },
    {
        url: process.argv[4],
        data: null
    }
];

holder.forEach((element) => {
    request(element.url,(err, response, body) => {
        element.data = body;
    });
});

while (true) {
    if (holder[0].data != null || holder[1].data != null || holder[2].data != null)
        break;
}

holder.forEach((element) => {
    console.log(element.data);
})
```

Comment: that's because JS is single thread so even if your requests get response, they haven't got time to fire the callback

Comment: Could it be because the request above the loop isn't finished when the loop starts running? So when the loop begins, those values are truly null.

Comment: @jhhoff02 But their values change some time after.

Comment: Good point, I thought about that after commenting.. Good luck

Comment: [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/)

Comment: @Andreas Thank you, but I have already solved the exercise. I am just curious about why this happens.